# Programatically creating a UIView with multiple Labels

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7, autolayout

**Xcode Interface Builder issue**
Personally I do not like the way that interface builder works in Xcode. In this example I am trying to create a fairly complex view controller. On the `viewDidLoad` of the view controller I show a custom alert view (as such). It is not actually an alert view but more of a view that shows the user some information. I have a dimmed background view and a view on top of this. If I try to create this in interface builder it gets overly complicated as you cannot select the views in the background and move them etc without dropping subviews into the wrong views and so on...

**Scenario**
What I am trying to do is create a View which holds some labels and a button. The view controller has a difficulty property based on this it will have different text in the labels/amount of labels.
I.e. Easy -- 3 labels
Hard -- 4 labels

I create the dimmedView and alert(styled)View like this:

```
// Setup the dimmedView
UIView *dimmedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
dimmedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.6];

// Setup the startingAlertView
UIView *startingAlertView = [[UIView alloc] init];
startingAlertView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

I then create the three/four labels based on some logic and add the necassary labels to the `startingAlertView` based on logic also.

The issue that is obvious is that at no point a frame for the view is set. This means that it is returning 0,0,0,0. What I would like to happen is the view to take the required height based on the labels added.

I am building for IOS7 and using Auto Layout. Should I be setting up constraints which would then adjust the relevant heights and locations in the view possibly?

Comment: @MarcoPace or, use auto layout, designed to solve exactly this problem.

Comment: @jrturton Good, I did't read last sentence. Since it is not using the IB I have wrongly assumed that he doesn't want to use them. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Thanks both, in this example IB is not useful... mainly because this is a top level view and has a complex view underneath. If you could toggle view to show/hide within IB whilst you work on others... now that would be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am building for IOS7 and using Auto Layout. Should I be setting up constraints which would then adjust the relevant heights and locations in the view possibly?

Yes. you don't use `initWithFrame:` under auto layout, or rather, you can, but the frame is ignored. Create your dimming view with a frame of `CGRectZero`, setting `translatesAutoresizingMasksToConstraints` to NO, add it to your main view and create constraints pinning it to all edges of the superview.

Then, add your alert view, again with a frame of zero and the `translates...` property set to NO. Create constraints to centre this view in your dimming view. This view will get its size from its subviews, since labels have an intrinsic size.

Add your labels as subviews of this view, with frame of zero and `translates...` set to NO. Depending on their content you may wish to set preferred max layout width or a width constraint.

Create constraints pinning your labels to the left and right edges of the superview, and lining your labels up in a vertical 'stack'. In each case you could add padding to give your alert a bit of a border.

This can look like a large amount of code, so you may want to read the articles I've written on [visual format for auto layout](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/) and [creating constraints in code](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/02/20/creating-individual-layout-constraints/), with the associated [autolayout convenience category](https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout) to make your life easier.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. Secondly the blog post is awesome, that REALLY helped me get to the answer myself. You are right it takes some code and playing around but that has massively helped in my understanding of coding the constraints instead so thanks!!!

Comment: Hi, I actually always used CGRectZero until I use this open source project https://github.com/BaiduLBS/BaiduMapKit, the most popular map kit in China. When instantiate its map view (subclass of UIView) in code and pass CGRectZero to init(frame:) it always shows incorrectly the first time! After the first time it can show correctly, any size bigger than zero won't have this problem. I never figure out why.  Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @Qiulang probably it's doing something with the frame values on initWithFrame, but that project doesn't have any source code so I can't tell. Raise an issue with them?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I raised an issue to them, they haven't replied yet. I also raised this issue to apple and apple is discussing with me. I asked apple if using CGRectZero is the best way to do it because I didn't see any "official" document mentions that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to the auto layout route, then you can add constraints that will keep the proper space between each label, and the proper space between the top and bottom of the view with the first and last labels. However, if you're not doing this in Interface Builder, you might as well skip using auto layout also, because it's fairly simple to just adjust the height of the view as you add labels.

You would start by setting the height of the view to the size of the top and bottom spaces that you want to have around the labels. Then each time you add a label, add to it the height of the label plus the height of the space you're putting between labels.

You could also wait until you've added all of the labels that you want, then set the height to the bottom label's y position plus its height plus the bottom space you want to have around the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using autolayout you can get the bounds from the parent view.

Here is a quick example, notice that we are not using frame, and using CGRectZero for our UILabels, the positioning comes from `updateConstraints` instead.  I am using [Visual Format Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html) to layout the labels which I recommend if you are doing it programatically.

Here we are making the labels the width of the parent view and then just stacked on top of each other.

```
#import "View.h"

@implementation View{
    UILabel *_label1;
    UILabel *_label2;
    UILabel *_label3;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        _label1.text = @"LABEL 1";

        _label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        _label2.text = @"LABEL 2";

        _label3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _label3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        _label3.text = @"LABEL 3";

        [self addSubview:_label1];
        [self addSubview:_label2];
        [self addSubview:_label3];
    }


    [self updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

    return self;
}

-(void)updateConstraints
{
    [super updateConstraints];

    NSDictionary *_viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_label1,_label2,_label3);


    // Set the contraintsto span the entire width of the super view
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[_label1]-|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:_viewsDictionary];

    [self addConstraints:constraints];

    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[_label2]-|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:_viewsDictionary];
    [self addConstraints:constraints];

    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[_label3]-|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:_viewsDictionary];

    [self addConstraints:constraints];


    // Last setup the vertical contraints other wise they will end up in a random place
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[_label1]-[_label2]-[_label3]"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:_viewsDictionary];
    [self addConstraints:constraints];
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```